# How do I fix this? (Python SSL error happening everywhere)

Tags: python, windows, ssl

Recently Python has started to act up. Badly. All versions of python I install and every python script I try to run that uses requests runs into the same error. Pip also shows this error any time I try to install a package. It's always along the lines of `Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)'))': /simple/requests/`. Since I reinstalled python to try to fix the error, I no longer have the requests library, but when I did, I could use `verify=False` when using `requests.get/post()` to fix the issue. I also tried switching networks and that didn't help either.

I also tried python on a couple other devices (Both ubuntu) and seem to be getting SSL-related errors but they do not appear to be related to this error.

I'm using Windows 11.

Any solutions?

Comment: If it worked before and stopped working suddenly than it might be related to changes in your environment - notably some device or software which intercepts SSL traffic in order to analyze it for malware. A unavoidable side effect of such interception is that the original server certificate will be replaced with a different certificate - which cause the certificate validation problems. Typical causes of such interception are a local antivirus software or some network-wide SSL interception with a corporate proxy/firewall.

Comment: This started happening probably about a week ago, and no noticeable environmental changes occurred. Before that there were some issues with requests related to proxies (even when I wasn't using any proxies) that I ignored for a while. The proxy-related errors were probably happening for about 2 or 3 months before this and I just never needed to fix it since it didn't affect making requests to most websites, and only affected requesting from a couple websites. Also, this is happening at home. Also, I checked my antivirus firewall and no changes have been made there. @SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by just reinstalling Python.